# Inherit a class but it's usually created with a static method?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've got a class that I would like to inherit. i.e. ExpenseForm should inherit from Spreadsheet. Spreadsheet is provided by a third party: I can't change it.

But parent class instances are usually generated with a static method:

```
Spreadsheet myExpenses = Spreadsheet.Open(filename);
```

(And Spreadsheet implements iDisposable, so the above statement is actually at the top of a using section, but I don't think that really affects this.)

I'd like to have

```
ExpenseForm myExpenses = ExpenseForm.Open(filename);
```

This fails, of course, since ExpenseForm.Open (inherited from Spreadsheet) returns a Spreadsheet object.

What's the best way to solve this? Maybe extension methods? (I have no experience with those.)

I've gone a different direction; ExpenseForm now has an instance of Spreadsheet. (This feels a little messier, since I have to keep track of my disposable object to clean up when I'm done.) But it seems like I'm missing a way to solve the original inheritance problem.

Comment: It looks like SpreadSheet was not meant to be derived from. In your place I'd make it an attribute of ExpenseForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can create your own `ExpenseForm.Open` method easily enough:

```
public static new ExpenseForm Open(string file)
{
    // Do whatever you need
}
```

That's assuming you *can* create a subclass, i.e. that there are appropriate constructors you can chain to. You say that you would *normally* use `Spreadsheet.Open`, but *are* there protected or public constructors available?

Personally I'd favour the composition route anyway - do you actually want other code to treat an `ExpenseForm` as if it were any other kind of `Spreadsheet`? I'm generally more of a fan of composition than inheritance - it makes code easier to reason about, in my experience.

Comment: There is a single protected constructor with no arguments, but I'll have to research more and see if I can appropriately initialize everything if I went that route. (It's the MS Office OpenXML SDK classes. For what I'm doing, I think it would be nice to get all spreadsheet functionality directly on my object, but I can always expose ExpenseForm.UnderlyingSpreadsheet.)

Answer (score 1):

If `Spreadsheet` objects can only be created by means of a static function, then inheritance is not an option. Just provide your own `Open` static function within `ExpenseForm` that returns an object of that kind.